# ng-show animation doesn't work when class is changed with ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate, ng-class, ng-show

For a div, I have an `ng-class` expression like this: `ng-class="{error: msg.isError}"` 
and an `ng-show` expression like this: `ng-show="msg.text"` 
As it's obvious, I want the div to be shown when `msg.text` is not empty, and I want it to have class 'error' when `msg.error` is true.
Also, I want it to fade in whenever it's going to be shown.
it works well when class is not changing, but when I set `msg.error` to true, and at the same time set a value for `msg.text`, animation doesn't occur.
here is the [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/403z4ypn/10/) of my problem.
This is the html:

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='cnt'>
<button ng-click="showText2()">This works</button>
<button ng-click="showText()">This doesn't work</button>
<button ng-click="clear()">Clear</button>
  <div ng-show="msg.text" ng-class="{error: msg.isError}" class="fadein fadeout">{{ msg.text }}</div>
</div>
```

and this is js code:

```
app = angular.module('app',['ngAnimate']);
app.controller('cnt', function($scope){
    $scope.showMsg = false;
    $scope.msg = {
        isError: false,
        text: ""
    };
    $scope.clear = function(){
        $scope.msg.isError = false;
        $scope.msg.text = "";
    }        
    $scope.showText = function(){ // This doesn't work
        $scope.msg.isError = true;
        $scope.msg.text = "text to fade in";
    }
    $scope.showText2 = function(){ // This works
        $scope.msg.text = "text to fade in";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `$scope.apply()` in the same time.

When `$scope.msg.text` is not empty, the ng-show is apply it, it's okay. If `$scope.msg.isError` is change, the ng-class will update class in the same time, the animation doesn't occur;

You can add timer, use $timeout delay 1 ms, Example : [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/allyusd/90cr1c9x/)

```
app = angular.module('app',['ngAnimate']);
app.controller('cnt', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.showMsg = false;
    $scope.msg = {
        isError: false,
        text: ""
    };
    $scope.clear = function(){
        $scope.msg.isError = false;
        $scope.msg.text = "";
    }        
    $scope.showText = function(){ // This doesn't work        
        $scope.msg.text = "text to fade in";

        // add timer, it's work now
        $timeout(function() {            
            $scope.msg.isError = true;
        }, 1);
    }
    $scope.showText2 = function(){ // This works
        $scope.msg.text = "text to fade in";
    }

}]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution works. However, I didn't got your explanation completely. I'll leave the question open for a while, for possible more explanation from others.

Answer (score 1):

Too late to answer but still,

When `ng-show` is true angular will add `ngHide` class to the element. So if `$scope.msg.isError` is true the `error` class is added at the same time as `ngHide` hence the animation won't work.

Here is the simple workaround

```html
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='cnt'>
    <button ng-click="showText2()">This works</button>
    <button ng-click="showText()">This doesn't work</button>
    <button ng-click="clear()">Clear</button>
      <div ng-show="msg.text" class="fadein fadeout">
        <span ng-class="{error: msg.isError}">{{ msg.text }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veerajDPoojary/ou6r9bzs/)

This is just a workaround and not a real solution because this may be a problem in the angular code itself.